# Change ActionMailer Email URL Host Dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

In my application.html.erb I have `<%= render @objects %>`, that renders a bunch of `_object.html.erb` partials, each with a `<%= link_to(object) %>`. I render the same single partial `<%= render @object %>` in the email that is being sent when somebody leaves a comment but I want link to start with a server url.

I have tried everything:

```
link_to(object)

url_for(object)

before_filter :set_mailer_host
def set_mailer_host
  ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port
end

default_url_options[:host] = "example.com"

def default_url_options
  { host: 'example.com' }
end
```

...Nothing works. With or without `:only_links`

In the end, I just built a dumb helper that prepends hostname to links:

```
# application_controller.rb
before_filter { App::request=request }

# application_helper.rb
def hostify obj
  "http://#{App::request.host_with_port}#{url_for obj}"
end

# _object.html.erb:
<%= link_to obj.title, hostify(object) %>
```

Is there a normal way to do this?

Comment: What do link_to(obj) and url_for(obj) have to do with anything? Oh, are those in your mailer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after spending some time with it, I think I am starting to figure it out.

You got to use restful routes then you can set `default_url_options[:host] = host` in the Mailer action and :only_path to true in `default_url_options` for other controllers. Plus `:locale`.

And in the view I have: `objects_url(object)`

Since I have different hostnames, I pass `request.host_with_port` as a parameter from a controller to the Mailer when sending mail.

`link_to` doesn't accept parameters and `url_for()` can only build url from parts of it.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really tell what you're trying to link to or what 'obj' is referring to, but you can do something like:

```
link_to obj.title, {:host => 'example.com'}
```

or

```
link_to obj.title, {:controller => 'store', :action => 'view_cart', :host => 'example.com'}
```

Comment: Well I am sending a partial inside of the email which is used on the site. `_obj.html.erb` so to speak. I do `render @obj` both in mail view and the controller view on the site. I have omitted some code, sorry.

Comment: In my application.html.erb I have `render @objects`, that renders a bunch of `_object.html.erb` partials, each with a `link_to(object)`. I render the same single partial in email when somebody leaves a comment but I want link to have a server url.

Comment: It really doesn't matter how you do anything other than that you add :host => 'example.com' to your link_to's

Comment: I could probably build a link using `objects_path(object)`. All I want is to have an automated solution for links so they are relative on site and absolute in Email. It should be simple with ActionMailer, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
def url_options
  { domain: 'example.com' }
end
```

Or better to merge in case you use other options:

```
def url_options
  { domain: 'example.com' }.merge(super)
end
```